# How can I have my python script display in html, and accept input from a webform to check against the script

Tags: python, html

I have looked around for an answer to this question, and I haven't been able to find one that seems clear to me. Basically, I am writing a python script that asks a user a question. Based on their answer (and some if/else statements) the script will return a string (and an image if I can figure it all out). Basically I want to have a webpage that displays the question string I print in python and has a form that accepts the answers, then checks that answer against the script, and returns the result. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of web server from Python to support this.  You can start as simple and mundane as [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), which *may* fit your needs perfectly, to something a bit more robust, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).  There are others out there as well:

- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/)

You'll also need to be mindful of templating, which typically comes in the form of [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/), [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/), or [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), which are compatible with all of these save for web.py (I think).